# Alternative to using map as key of map in GO

Tags: go

I want to tag my maps with a timestamp, there will be various maps - dynamically generated. The keys will be repeated, so if the same map appears I want to updated its values

I'm getting the maps from external sources and want to registered when they are read

Ever so often I want to iterate the map and find those maps that didn't update for a while

```golang
a = map[string]string{"a":1, "b":2}
b = map[map[string]string]time.Time{}
b[a] = 1
```

I understand it's not supported but I was wondering what are the some ways of doing it?
The first thing that comes to mind is: serialize the map into string and use it as key,,?

Comment: It might help to elaborate a bit more. Do you have many such maps? A fixed number or dynamic? How do you want to set and use said timestamp?

Comment: How about making a struct consisting of time.Time field and your map?

Comment: @AntonMatveiev - The issue is I want to lookup by the map[string]string

Comment: @Marc added some explaination

Comment: @aclokay the point is to eliminate the need to look up by *anything*.

Comment: @hobbs what do you mean it's the point? If I don't look up how am I supposed to find the data I'm looking for ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a struct that will keep the info you need:

```
type MyMap struct {
     timestamp time.Time
     m map[string]string
}
```

And lookup by iterating over a slice of such structs:

```
func lookup(needle map[string]string, haystack []MyMap) (MyMap, bool) {
    for _, myMap := range haystack {
        if reflect.DeepEqual(needle, myMap.m) {
            return myMap, true
        }
    }
    return nil, false
}
```

Alternatively, convert your map to JSON and use the result as the key:

```
b, _ := json.Marshal(myMap)
key := string(b)
m, ok := myMaps[key] // myMaps is map[string]MyMap
if !ok {
    myMaps[key] = myMap
}
```

Apparently, `json.Marshal` sorts the map's keys before marshaling, so this should be a reliable solution.